# Spring boot - Hibernate JPA not creating MySql DB table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I know that this question can be a duplicate but none of those solutions are working for me.

I want the tables to be created automatically. However, when I am sending POST request with the USER object in JSON format to the server, I get the below exception.

Exception:

```
    {
  "timestamp": 1490023621440,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException",
  "message": "PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO user(lastName, firstName, dob, phone, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'master_slave.user' doesn't exist",
  "path": "/main"
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${writerendpoint}:${port}/${database.name}
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.driver

writerendpoint=localhost
port=3306
database.name=master_slave

spring.session.store-type=none

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Specify the DBMS
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Ddl auto must be set to "create" to ensure that Hibernate will run the
# import.sql file at application startup
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

# SQL dialect for genereting optimized queries
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=master_slave
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;
    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    @Max(value=15)
    private String lastName;
    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    @Max(value=15)
    private String firstName;   
    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    private Date dob;
    @Column
    @Max(value=10)
    private String phone;
    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    @Email
    private String email;
    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    @Min(value=6)
    @Max(value=15)
    private String password;

and their getters and setters.
```

MainDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("mysql")
public class MainDaoImpl implements MainDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.app.masterSlave.dao.RegistrationDao#userRegistration(com.app.masterSlave.model.User)
     */
    @Override
    public void userRegistration(User user) {
        final String sql="INSERT INTO user(lastName, firstName, dob, phone, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        final String lastName=user.getLastName();
        final String firstName=user.getFirstName();
        final Date dob=user.getDob();
        final String phone = user.getPhone();
        final String email = user.getEmail();
        final String password = user.getPassword();
//      BCryptPasswordEncoder encodedPassword = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();            
//      final String password = encodedPassword.encode(user.getPassword());

        int success = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] {lastName, firstName, dob, phone, email, password});

        if(success==0) {
            System.out.println("There was an error while insertion.");

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Row with email: " + email + " inserted successfully.");

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see any exceptions when the application is started?

Comment: No I don't see any error when application starts. I see a kind of warning give below:
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

Comment: `<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>` have you added in pom ?

Comment: Yes I have.
<dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.5</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @EnableAutoConfiguration is present in your main ApplicationClass?

Comment: Try - spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update or If table already present in DB, drop the user table and restart the application

Comment: Hi Prathap,
I don't have '@EnableAutoConfiguration' in the main application class.However, I have '@SpringBootApplication' in it and it will cover the '@EnableAutoConfig' annotation. 

I also tried using 'update' instead of 'create', but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring hibernate for JPA, but than you insert the user by SQL.

If the configurations of JPA and JDBC template are not compatible, you will face problems, as the one you posted. To avoid this, you may consider doing all database operations only in JPA or only in JDBC.

The url you are using

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${writerendpoint}:${port}/${database.name}
```

already contains the database name 'master_slave'. Additionally you are setting the JPA default schema to the same name

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=master_slave
```

Which may be just superfluous, or the cause of your problem. Remove it and give it a try.

Have a look at the database. Which tables are created by hibernate ? are they in the database you are expecting ?

Comment: Hi Stefan,

Thanks for your reply. Actually I added the second property just recently and was not there before. I was facing the same error when that property was not even there. 

For the DB, I don't see any tables being created in it.

I wanted to use JdbcTemplate for DB operations but also wanted hibernate to manage the DDL part itself. 

Any thoughts what i should do?